# UTF8 To UTF16 Conversion using NDK

Tags: java, c++, utf-8, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am working on an Android app which has lots of c++(Native) code so I am using JNI to interact with Java part of the application. Now I want to convert my strings from UTF8 to UTF16 and vice versa in my native code.
For that I am using the JNI functions.

Here is the code to convert from UTF8 to UTF16.

```
//Create New jString using the utf8 string.

jstring jStr = env->NewStringUTF(str.c_str());

//Now we have a jstring which keeps the data in unicode format 
// so get the UTF16 data from the JString.

const jchar *utf16Raw = env->GetStringChars(jStr, JNI_FALSE);

if (utf16Raw != nullptr) {
   //Use Unicode data
}
```

But I have doubt that whether this logic is correct, or fo I need to move my jstring to JAVA side using JNI and there convert the jstring from utf8 to utf16?

Comment: Why do you doubt your logic is correct? Is it not working? You can certainly use the VM as a MUTF8-to-UTF16 converter, but bear in mind that you're allocating a String object each time. If your only interest is string format conversion, you can find C++ code that does the conversion directly. FWIW, UTF-16 isn't great (see http://utf8everywhere.org/), so carefully consider whether or not it's the best thing to work with.

Comment: The logic is working fine. I just wanted to be doubly sure. Internally we are using UTF8 everywhere.

Comment: If you use UTF8 everywhere, why do you want to convert to/from UTF16?

Comment: Are you sure that you have _modified_ UTF-8 in your std::string? That's what NewStringUTF takes.

Comment: [Working Around JNI UTF-8 Strings](http://banachowski.com/deprogramming/2012/02/working-around-jni-utf-8-strings/): "*In the case of passing strings from native back to Java, the JNI definitely crashes if not in correctly modified UTF-8*"